# Why does using lz4 lib to decompress data fail but works fine when using unlz4?

Tags: c, lz4

I'm writing some code to decompress an LZ4 encoded buffer. The operation fails when calling `LZ4_decompress_safe`. The error given is 'ERROR_contentChecksumFlag_invalid'. There is nothing wrong with the input data, because I wrote the same buffer out to a file and used unlz4 to decode it fine. The lz4-dev lib version I'm using is 1.7.1 (Xenial Ubuntu Pkg).

The lz4 lib that unlz4 uses is 1.7.1. I'm at a loss of what the issue is.

The code I'm using:

```
std::ofstream dbgfile("~/lz4_dbg", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
dbgfile.write(entry_buffer, entry_size);
dbgfile.close();

char* lz4_buffer = (char*)calloc(1, entry_size*4);
uint64_t bytes_decompressed = LZ4_decompress_safe(entry_buffer, lz4_buffer, entry_size, entry_size * 4); 

std::string err = LZ4F_getErrorName(bytes_decompressed);
```

Comment: Where do you check for errors in that code?

Comment: Last line. `LZ4F_getErrorName(bytes_decompressed)`. LZ4_decompress_safe returns -4.

Comment: `LZ4_decompress_safe()` returns an int, but you're storing it in an `uint64_t` and then using a `LZ4F_` function on that? That doesn't seem right? And was your data compressed with LZ4 or LZ4F functions? I doubt the two are compatible.

Comment: I was storing it in an int, but thought to try uint64_t for shits and giggles. Reruning it with int64_t provides the same error result. I'm not sure which functions it was compressed with. This is data from the internet. I can give that a try and report back.

Answer (score 2):

So the problem was that I just wasn't familiar with the lz4 library and didn't realize there was two different ways to decompress lz4 data (via LZ4 or LZ4Framing).

Using regular LZ4 failed, but switching to LZ4Framing worked.

Thanks Shawn.